# Remove text between characters

Tags: sublimetext2

I have some character I need to remove, basically I have some locations separated by comma.

ex: ,16124">Mesas (las),16125">Minglanilla,16126">Mira,16128),

I need in sublime text to remove all information including what is between.

In this example I need to remove 1624"> | 16125">...

I already tried to find in sublime any functionality of this type where i could select regular expression but have no idea where is located.

Any idea how i could achieve it in sublime text or any other editor?

Answer (score 0):

On Sublime Text 2 Go to `Find-> Replace...` or `Find-> Find...`
then click on the first symbol in the bottom bar (like in the image below, to allow regular expression)

[image]

Then if you want to find the strings like 1624"> use this `([0-9])*">`. 
This find all group of number followed by " and >.

Then you Replace all with empty space.